# How to send S3 bucket region name to a json file using Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am creating a S3 bucket using Terraform, I need to send the region name `aws_s3_bucket.website_bucket.region` in which the bucket was created to a json file (`root/region.json`) in the below format.

*root/region.json*

```
{
   "region": "us-east-2"
}
```

*root/s3.tf*

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "website_bucket" {
  bucket   = var.website_bucket_name
  provider = aws.east
  acl      = "public-read"

  cors_rule {
    allowed_headers = ["*"]
    allowed_methods = ["PUT", "POST", "GET", "DELETE"]
    allowed_origins = ["*"]
  }

  website {
    index_document = "index.html"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should accomplish the task:

```
resource "local_file" "region" {
  filename = "root/region.json"
  content  = jsonencode({
    "region": aws_s3_bucket.website_bucket.region,
  })
}
```